# python how to split string with more than one character?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, split, delimiter

I would like to split a string as below

`1234ABC` into `123` and `ABC`

`2B` into `2` and `B`

`10E` into `10` and `E`

I found `split` function does not work because there is no `delimiter`

Comment: Did you intend to split `1234ABC` into `123` and `ABC`? If so, what was the criteria for ignoring the `4` in the middle? In fact what is your criteria for splitting for the examples you've shown?

Comment: It's not clear that you want to parse the number from the string. Please, edit your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby` with boolean `isdigit` function.

```
from itertools import groupby

test1 = '123ABC'
test2 = '2B'
test3 = '10E'

def custom_split(s):
    return [''.join(gp) for _, gp in groupby(s, lambda char: char.isdigit())]

for t in [test1, test2, test3]:
    print(custom_split(t))

# ['123', 'ABC']
# ['2', 'B']
# ['10', 'E']
```

Answer (score 2):

This can quite  easily be accomplished using the `re` module:

```
>>> import re
>>> 
>>> re.findall('[a-zA-Z]+|[0-9]+', '1234ABC')
['1234', 'ABC']
>>> re.findall('[a-zA-Z]+|[0-9]+', '2B')
['2', 'B']
>>> re.findall('[a-zA-Z]+|[0-9]+', '10E')
['10', 'E']
>>> # addtionall test case
... 
>>> re.findall('[a-zA-Z]+|[0-9]+', 'abcd1234efgh5678')
['abcd', '1234', 'efgh', '5678']
>>>
```

The regex use is very simple. Here is quick walk through:

- `[a-zA-Z]+`: Match one or more alphabetic characters lower case or upper
- `|` or...
- `[0-9]+`: One or more whole numbers

Answer (score 2):

Another way to solve it using re package

```
r = re.search('([0-9]*)([a-zA-Z]*)', test_string)
r.groups()
```